# How to properly search and replace in python some rows in a file (with fileinput)?

Tags: python, file, replace, printing

I have a file `test_file.py` that I would like to alter with a code, more precisely to search and replace particular lines in this file, but leave all other lines to be preserved in their original form. The simplified form of the file is something like this:

```
line1 = 'abc'
line2 = 'abc'
line3 = 'abc'
line4 = 'abc'
```

I am using the following simplified snippet to make search-and-replace changes to the file only in lines `line1` and `line3`:

```
import fileinput

for line in fileinput.input('test_file.py', inplace=True):
    if line.startswith('line1 ='):
        line = line.replace(line, "line1 = 'ABC'")
        sys.stdout.write(line)
        sys.stdout.write('\n')
    if line.startswith('line3 ='):
        line = line.replace(line, "line3 = 'ABC'")
        sys.stdout.write(line)
        sys.stdout.write('\n')
    else:
        sys.stdout.write(line)
```

The expected resulting file `test_file.py` should look something like this:

```
line1 = 'ABC'
line2 = 'abc'
line3 = 'ABC'
line4 = 'abc'
```

Instead, the result looks like:

```
line1 = 'ABC'
line1 = 'ABC'line2 = 'abc'
line3 = 'ABC'
line4 = 'abc'
```

What am I doing wrong and how can I achieve the expected output? Alternative solutions that don't make use of the `fileinput` package are also welcome. Tnx!

Comment: If you're replacing the entire `line`, just do `line = "line1 = 'ABC'"`

Comment: The second `if` should be `elif`. Otherwise, the `else:` block is only associated with the second `if`, not the first one.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I assumed the problem is somehow in the syntax about printing the statements, not in the way I created the loops. So it's a valuable lesson!